# set while loop to execute for specific time

Tags: microcontroller

how to make a while loop to execute for specific amount of time(say 5 secs)??

```
while(1)
  {
   int time=0,timeinsec=5;
    while(timeinsec>=time)
    {
    ADMUX = 0xC1;
    ADCSRA = 0xE7;           // wait until conversion starts
    while((ADCSRA & (1<ADIF))==0);    // wait for convarsion to be finish

    lcd_out(1,1,"Current");
    lcd_out(2,1,"temp. is");
    Delay_ms(10);
    a = ADCL;
    b = ADCH;
    a=(a*2.56/1024)*100;
    inttostr(a,disp);
    if (a>=35 && a<40)
    {

      lcd_out(3,1,disp);
      delay_ms(200);
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);

    }
    else if(a>40)
    {
    Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);

    lcd_out(2,1,disp);
    lcd_out(3,1,"High Temp.:");

     lcd_out(4,1,"Sending Msg.");
    delay_ms(200);
    }
    else{
    Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);

    lcd_out(3,1,"normal");
    delay_ms(200);
   // UART1_Write(disp);
    }
    //lcd_out(3,1,disp);
   }
    // UART1_Init(9600);
    while(timeinsec>=time)
    {
    ADMUX = 0xC0;
    ADCSRA = 0xE7;           // wait until conversion starts
    while((ADCSRA & (1<ADIF))==0);    // wait for convarsion to be finish

    lcd_out(1,1,"Current");
    lcd_out(2,1,"Press. is");
    Delay_ms(10);
    a = ADCL;
    b = ADCH;
    a=(a*2.56/1024)*100;
    inttostr(a,disp);
    if (a>=35 && a<40)
    {

      lcd_out(3,1,disp);
      delay_ms(200);
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);

    }
    else if(a>40)
    {
    Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);

    lcd_out(2,1,disp);
    lcd_out(3,1,"High Pres.:");

     lcd_out(4,1,"Sending Msg.");
    delay_ms(200);
    }
    else{
    Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);

    lcd_out(3,1,"normal Pres");
    delay_ms(200);
   // UART1_Write(disp);
    }
    //lcd_out(3,1,disp);
   }
   }  //UART1_Write(disp);        // and send data via UART

}
```

the outer while loop is executing infinite times & i want to male the inner first while loop to execute for 5 secs & then inner second while loop foor 5 secs & this should happen infinite times(while(1))...

so how is it possible????

Comment: Have you tried using a timer?

Comment: I don't want to read 100 lines of code to debug a loop; you could help us to help you by paring down your loop and timing elements to the minimum that reproduce the issue

Comment: Use a timer. Have it set a flag when it fires. Check for the flag in your while() statement.

Comment: Replace the '1' in while(1) with something a little less permanent...

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is

- Configure a timer accordingly to the microcontroller oscillating frequency.
- Set up a timer interrupt

Combination of Interrupt and Timer will do the trick.

Can't help you much further without knowing the microcontroller model, but here's an [example](http://playground.arduino.cc/code/timer1) of what I mean

Comment: Based on the "UART1" commented out everywhere, I'd say it has at least 3 timers, and uses "TIMER" in its ISRs.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Looks like an ATxxxxx series, not sure if it's ATmegaxxx or something else. But It definitely isn't ATtiny if it has UART1 instead of UART

Answer (score 1):

With Arduino (or AVR in general for that matter) you sometimes have the need to execute some code at regular intervals. A timed interrupt routine is the proper solution, This can be quite complicated for those who are unfamiliar with directly programming the hardware.

I created a simple [proof of concept](https://git.linformatronics.nl/gitweb/?p=millisecondInterrupt;a=summary) code that runs on AVR-type Arduino’s (and is easily ported to bare AVR) and uses a timed interrupt to time exact 1 ms, based on the 16MHz system clock. Thus 1000 counts equals 1 second with the same accuracy as the system clock. As proof the standard LED on pin 13 will start to blink in a 0.5Hz rhythm, one second on, one second off.

Timer0 and Timer1 are commonly used for the Arduino and third party libraries, so that leaves us with Timer2. Arduino’s system clock runs at 16MHz. Timer2 is clocked through a prescaler, this basically means that the system clock is first divided before it is fed to the Timer/Counter. I selected a 128 prescaler by configuring TCCR2B. This means the Timer/Counter is clocked at 16MHz / 128 = 125kHz.

Next I decided to make Timer/Counter2 compare to a set value 125 by setting OCR2A to 125 and configuring ‘Clear Timer on Compare’-bit in TCCR2A. This results in an exact 1kHz interrupt. TIMSK2 is configured to enable the Timer/Counter2 CompareA interrupt. Then all that is left is to attach the interrupt to some code, which is done with the ISR( TIMER2_COMPA_vect ) command. The Interrupt Service Routine counts to 1000 and so we arrive at 1 second ticks which can be used in the main loop to make the LED blink.

[Link to original article](http://blog.linformatronics.nl/213/electronics/timed-1-millisecond-interrupt-routine-for-arduino)

Answer (score 0):

If you need precision, learn about Timers in your microcontroler platform.

But if you don´t, you will need to now approximately how many interactions you need in the loop to reach the 5 seconds,

you can use while loop or a for loop like this

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<20;i++){ //I choose 20interactions in first try
// your code
}
```

Then measure the seconds to do this 20 interactions, finally make a calc

(20interactions * 5s) / Seconds measured  =  how many interactions you need to reach 5 seconds